# C++ special characters

Tags: c++, character-encoding, internationalization

I have the following problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
   string data = "\xd7\x91\xd7\x90" ; 

   data << data<<endl;
}
```

The output is: בא

But with an input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char rrr[100];
    cout << "Please enter your string:" ;   
    scanf("%s",rrr);

    cout<< rrr <<endl;
}
```

The input I type is: `\xd7\x91\xd7\x90`

The output I see on the screen is: `\xd7\x91\xd7\x90`

So my question is how can I convert the input `\xd7\x91\xd7\x90` to `בא`?

Comment: You could type "בא" directly...

Comment: You should replace all `"\xAB"` in your input string with `(char)(A*16+B)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your scanf statement:

```
int a, b, c, d;
if (scanf("\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x\\x%x", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4)
    // a, b, & c have been read/parsed successfully...
    std::cout << (char)a << (char)b << (char)c << (char)d << '\n';
```

Still, it's better to learn to stream in hex values ala:

```
char backslash, x;
char c;

while (std::cin >> backslash >> x >> std::hex >> c && backslash == '\\' && x == 'x')
    // or "for (int i = 0; i < 4 && std::cin >> ...; ++i)" if you only want four
    std::cout << c;
```

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't help . I need to convert this \xd7\x91\xd7\x90 to אב because I get it from a html form which I can't change.

Comment: Just find "\x" at position `pos` and do `sscanf(str+pos, "\\x%x", a)` then use `(char)a` to get magic symbol

Comment: @roihatam: the code that you say is working in your question stores and streams that text as 4 single-byte characters (as distinct from 2 wide-characters). The code above does pretty much the same (except that I hadn't noticed you had 4 bytes, and wrote code for 3 - will change). What exactly doesn't work? What gets displayed? Are you using UNIX, Windows, a console/xterm/gnome-terminal, outputting to a file and viewing (and if so in what app)?

Comment: everything works fine but I want to convert \xd7\x91\xd7\x90 to אב

Comment: @roihatam: And what is it converting it to?